# Ties in the data

Tags: correlation, estimation, ties

Are there any "good" ways to eliminate the effects of ties in a data set for statistical analysis? For example, in finding the correlation between two series which has lots of ties?

I would like to estimate the dependence between two series by a Pearson correlation coefficient and other correlation measures, like Kendall's tau. However, I don't know whether Pearson's correlation coefficient, or any other coefficient, is good for such data. The data set is around 40K observations, both variables take values in [0,1], and there are lots of ties (around 20K) at 0 and 1.

Comment: Although dealing with ties can be an issue in some analyses of categorical data and in applying certain nonparametric methods to continuous data, ties *per se* create no problems for computing correlations.  Perhaps you could say a little more about the data you are concerned about?

Comment: Ties are not necessarily a thing to be avoided. If the data is so for a good reason (and not erroneously so), there is no need (barring some nonparametric tests if my memory serves me well) to account for ties, and everything should work as planned...

Comment: Actually, I would like to estimate the dependence between two series by a Pearson correlation coefficient and other correlation measures, like Kendall's tau. However, I dont know whether Pearson's correlation coefficient, or any other coefficient, is good for such a data. The data set is around 40K observations, and both variables take values in [0,1] and there are lots of ties (around 20K) are at 0 and 1.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the clarification.  I took the liberty of putting it directly in the question so that all readers are aware of what you are trying to cope with.  It would be good to know more about why so many ties might arise.  Are you able to tell us what those observations represent?  If you can, please go ahead and edit the question itself.